# How to start and stop collecting profile data for gprof

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, profiling, gprof

I am using gprof to analyze the flat profile of a C++ program. However, since I have expensive setup and tear-down code that I don't want to go into the profile, I'd like to trigger collecting data only for a certain block. I'd like to do something like:

```
void foo() {
 --- start collecting ---
  do stuff
 --- stop collecting
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789310/enable-and-disable-gprof-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

`gprof`'s documentation describes that the generation of profiling data is controlled by a simple `-pg` compiler switch.

Therefore, it seems logical to me to factor out the expensive setup and teardown code into a separate source file, and compile that source file without the `-pg` compiler switch.

Comment: gprof has two sources of data: periodic samples from itimer (`setitimer` will ask kernel to send special signal 100 times per second; low overhead) to get profile; and callgraph information from compiler instrumentation (high overhead for every call). Turning off `-pg` for some sources will disable only second source of data, which will speed up code from that file, but not completely turn off profiling. (First source should be enabled by -pg option to linking step to get gmon.out file)

Answer (score -1):

You have to build your critical fuction in a diferente source with -pg and then